# unable to integrate mailjet in ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailjet

i am new to ruby-on-rails and due to project requirements ive been trying to integrate mailjet to my project. i had followed this link 
    https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-gem but unable to integrate it properly.
in config/development.rb i am having

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :mailjet
```

and my mailjet.rb is also properly created but when im trying to send mail i am getting

```
undefined delivery method :mailjet
```

and
    OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (hostname “localhost” does not match the server certificate)

i am using rails 4 and ruby 2.

when i integrated mailjet on localmachine within no time it started working but when i am following same steps on prod server i'm getting above errors.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer , actually i had forgot to restart unicorn server that was the reason my mailjet varible was getting undifined,
from console i ran command

```
etc/init.d/service unicorn_<project-name> restart.
```

thats it.